spring data keyvalue map detect duplicate keys
can spring data keyvalue detect duplicate keys ?
batch result :

readCount=116361, filterCount=23687, writeCount=92674 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=4655

i managed to define a composite key :
public record LocationKey (String countryCode, String locationCode) implements Serializable {

}
and in the ItemProcessor :
.withKey(new LocationKey(item.countryCode(), item.locationCode()));

in the ItemWriter :
toWrite.add(chunk.size());
            repository.saveAll(chunk).iterator().forEachRemaining((i) -> written.increment());

gives this result :

toWrite : 92674
 written : 92674
 locations in repository : 92571

so the doc indeed says :

Returns:the saved entities; will never be null. The returned Iterable will have the same sizeas the Iterable passed as an argument.

this is true , so how can i be notified which duplicate keys there were ?
should i use another map implementation in order to get the wanted behavior ?

spring boot 3.4.1
spring data keyvalue 3.4.1
spring batch 5.2.1


@EnableMapRepositories(,mapType = MultiValueMap.class)

[@EnableMapRepositories(,mapType = MultiValueMap.class) ] throws inline .LinkedMultiValueMap cannot be cast to class java.util.List however [@Bean
public KeyValueOperations keyValueTemplate() {
return new KeyValueTemplate(keyValueAdapter());
}
@Bean
public KeyValueAdapter keyValueAdapter() {
return new MapKeyValueAdapter(MultiValueMap.class);
}] passes and throws [DuplicateKeyException]
